# Change image when button is pressed

Tags: ios, c, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton

In the app I have six buttons and when any of these buttons are pressed I want the image in the center of the screen to change to a different image but just for the time that any of the six buttons are being pressed. I am really struggling with this and all help would be appreciated. I am using a .xib file. Thanks again guys I am tearing my hair out with exasperation.

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider voting up and ticking the right answer if the comments helped you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a responder(s) in your viewcontroller that is linked to all the button(s) on the viewcontroller through interface builder. In IB, to link a button to a method make sure the method is in your viewcontroller.h file and also implemented in the .m file. Then go to the connections panel in IB (after clicking on the button) and drag a connection from 'Touch Up Inside' (touch up inside is when a user touches the button and releases that touch up and inside the button's boundary) to the viewcontroller.xib window onto the file's owner icon. From there you will be presented with a drop down menu that will let you choose the IBAction methods you specified in the header file.

In this case take:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender; // header file



- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender { // .m file
   // when the button is pressed then change the uiimageview
   [imageView image: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: @"image.png"]];
}
```

Comment: Within the View controller I have an image view, I do not have an outlet even to show the original file because I feared that it would interfere. How would I add the original image before the touch is received. If you can help with that a tick is yours my friend

Comment: You can use this code for all the six buttons with a different image associated for each button. "image.png" will be whatever image you want to display on the View. Say for button 1 you want "image1.png", then use image1 for button1's code. For button2 use a different image.

Comment: `imageWithContentsOfFile:` expects a filepath as a parameter - not a name. For what you are trying to do you need to use `imageNamed:` instead to pick up an image from within the application bundle.

Comment: Abizem is correct. You should use - 
image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];